# Measuring load on an sqlite database

Tags: linux, sqlite

This is a long shot but are there any tools, built in or third party that allow you to see data like total load, queries per minute, number of processes waiting for lock on an sqlite database? Multiple processes are sharing one sqlite db. We want to find out whether it's a bottleneck in an application or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is not a client/server database, so there is no central server that would be able to collect this information.

All applications access the same database file, so you have to use the mechanisms of your OS to monitor accesses/locks on this file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of a tool, but you can do some simple analysis with `lslocks`. Eg:

```
$ flock /tmp/b sleep 100 &
$ flock /tmp/b sleep 10 &
$ lslocks | grep /tmp/b
flock           32752 FLOCK 18.4K WRITE* 0          0          0 /tmp/b
flock           32750 FLOCK 18.4K WRITE  0          0          0 /tmp/b
```

The `*` shows process 32752 is waiting for a write lock on the file,
whilst 32750 has a write lock.